Managing SSO for Multi-Domain and Local Deployments in a Django Application?
I am developing a Django application that will be offered in a marketplace. Each customer will have a unique domain, differentiated at least by prefixes. I have integrated Single Sign-On (SSO) for authentication.
I have two specific questions regarding SSO management in this multi-domain setup:

Domain Registration with SSO Providers: For each new customer, do I need to manually register each new domain with the SSO provider, or is there a method within Django or the SSO provider's services that can automate this process?

Local Deployment SSO Configuration: I plan to allow customers to optionally run the application locally. I've noticed that SSO providers differ in their local testing configurations, with Google using 127.0.0.1 and Microsoft using localhost. How can I accommodate these differences in a seamless manner?


Thanks in advance
For now I don't have any extra domains, so it is working properly...so just wanted to know about this when I try out.
